# Getting the object variable name for the new object

Tags: javascript, variables, logging, constructor, variable-assignment

I have an object constructor such as:

```
function myObjConstr () {
    console.log(object_name);
}
```

I want this results:

```
var name1 = new myObjConstr(); //print in console log "name1"
var nameff = new myObjConstr(); //print in console log "nameff"
```

Comment: There is not association between an Object and it's assignment variable.  IOW: Not possible.

Comment: just define a field, namely "name", in your object and set the initial value when you create an instance of that object

Comment: Please explain why you need to do this. What problem will being able to do this solve? Since as shown below, it;s possible to mimic this with object names and such, but usually there's better solutions to the problem that this would solve.

Comment: Objects do not intrinsically have ‘names’ themselves. Rather, variables ‘name’ objects: x = y = {}. This new object, accessible via the ‘names’ x and y, does not have any knowledge of the expressions it has been used as or ‘names’ that evaluate to it.

Comment: @user2864740 Nice, 
var x = y = new myObjConstr();
but logically there is no problem if there is something like that in javascript that returns  assigned variable name  in object constructor.

Comment: var x = y = new myObjConstr();
result in console.log:
"x" then "y" normally ..Why this is not available in javascript?

Comment: (this.constructor) is set in javascript object constructor, i want  assigned variable name also or return "" if not assigned to variable simply.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to pass the object name to the constructor:

```
function myObjConstr (obj_name) {
    this.object_name = obj_name;
    console.log(this.object_name);
}

var name1 = new myObjConstr("name1");
var nameff = new myObjConstr("nameff");
```

Comment: thank for your answer, i don't want send var name in function arguments.
I do not like repeating the codes :)

Comment: What do you mean? This is the standard for creating objects. It's not normal practice to reference a variable name within the code the way you're trying. The variable name is just a reference/pointer towards the actual data. The name should be stored within the object

Comment: @MostafaMaher Variable names do not matter, expect them to get minified or something else. Not all objects are even assigned to any variable at all. If you need names, use strings.

Comment: @Bergi yes, if the object isn't assigned to variable .. return "" simply :)

Comment: function myObjConstr (obj_name) {
console.log(this.constructor);
}
why Why not be so this.assignedVariableName for example?!!

Comment: @MostafaMaher So if it doesn't really matter and you're fine with `""` as well, why do you care about the name at all? What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Answer (score 1):

you can make a function constructor myObjConstr(), thenafter you can make new myObjConstr().

1) function constructor

```
function myObjConstr (objName) {
    this.objName = objName;
}
```

2) make object of type myObjConstr

```
var name1 = new myObjConstr("name1");
var name2 = new myObjConstr("name2");
```

3) if you want to print the value,

```
console.log(name1.objName)
```

Comment: i don't want pass the variable name to the constructor in arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the variable name to the constructor. Instead you can convert an `array` of names of variables to array of `objects`

```js
let names = [
  'name1',
  'nameff'
]
let objects = names.map(name => myObjConstr(name));
function myObjConstr(name){
  this.name = name;
  console.log(this.name);
}
```